# Files above 4 GB, shows wrong file size in FTP and not working correct

Tags: ftp, streaming

I encountered a really annoying problem, and i hope you can help :)

File location: TP-Link Archer 2600 with HDD attatched

Okay, so on this HDD i have some video files (.mkv) that i stream on a raspberry pi on another location. If the file is below 4 GB, no problem at all! It's all working fine.

If the file is above 4 GB, the problems start to appear: If i try to stream this it will only show part of the video (like 20-30 minutes).

Example:

- I have a video file on 5.2 GB
- this video is about 2 hours and .mkv file
- When i stream on the raspberry pi, it stops after 25 minutes with no alerts or any
  message
- i go and check in FTP, and it says the file is only 768 MB!
- i check other files. All files below 4 GB shows with the correct file
  size. All above 4 GB shows a lot smaller file size.
- i go to filezilla to try and download the file to a computer the
  download bar reach 100% at 768 MB, but the download continues.
- At 5.2 GB it stops, and it has downloaded the entire file.

Why the **** does it think the file is smaller than it actually is? I don't want to download the file every time.

Ofc. i have checked that the HDD connected to the router is formated as NTFS, and there is no problems in transfering files to the HDD

I asked TP-Link if there was a file size limit, but she said it was 4 TB...

Any idea what could cause this, and where to start looking for errors? :)

Comment: How do you stream the files? Via FTP? Or some other protocol? The FTP server may have a bug.

Comment: For starters: The FTP server is using 32 bits for file size numbers -> 2^32 + 768 * 2^20 is approximately 5.2GB

Comment: I think Hannu is on the right track.  Can you verify whether you're running a 64-bit or 32-bit OS on the client side, and if it's 64-bit, do you have the 64-bit version of Filezilla installed?

Comment: Streaming through FTP yes :)
I'm not sure if filezilla is 64-bit, i will check when i get home (windows is 64-bit), but in the end it should stream on the raspberry pi with osmc installed, and this has the same problem with the file size, only this can only download 768 mb (in this example), but filezilla will download it all, just showing a wrong download percentage in the download bar.

Comment: The bit-ness of the program is irrelevant. Unless the program is buggy, number data types do not depend on the architecture. Only pointers will have a different size. So that means the FTP server is buggy and you should report this to TP-Link. Just describe the error like you did above.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I actually did send this to TP-Link, and just got the regular answer: restart the router and factory reset and that stuff. I did it ofc, but it didn't help. I will try and write to them again.